# Sharing a list between Python modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

SO feedback motivated me to create a package with often used routines, so I don't have to copy/paste functions into new modules any more. This works well, but now I encountered a problem. My module 2 function `f2` is supposed to be called from module 1 with a number `n1`. If `list1` exists in module 1, `f2` uses it to analyse `n1`, otherwise it has to create `list2` from scratch for this analysis. My approach so far is to use optional arguments.

**module1.py**

```
from standardpackage.module2 import f2
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
n = 1
a = f2(n, list1)               #works with existing list1
b = f2(n)                      #works without list1
```

**module2.py**

```
def f2(n, *arg):
    if arg:
        list2 = arg[0]         #uses list1
    else:
        list2 = [3, 2, 1]      #uses its own list

    res = dosth(n, list2)      #code executed within module2
    return res
```

This approach does, what it is supposed to do, but imho it doesn't look clever. I know from experience, that `list1` can be very long and `f2()` might be called millions of times. To create a copy of `list1` every time, you call `f2()`, seems to waste time and memory space.

**My question** is: Can `module 2` somehow use `list1` from `module 1`?

I read on SO and tutorial websites about global variable sharing and understand now, why my `global list1` approach didn't work. I've seen suggestions to bind module 1 to module 2, but I want to use module 2 in future projects, so I don't know the name of those modules. I've seen suggestions with threading and multiprocessing, but as a Python newbie, I didn't understand the relevance to my question. Any suggestions welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can directly pass `arg[0]` to the `dosth` function rather than copying arg[0] into list2

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid copying by passing arg[0] to the `dosth` function directly, also did a few changes to your code

```
def f2(n, *arg):
    if not arg:
        list2 = [3, 2, 1]         
        return dosth(n, list2)

    return dosth(n, arg[0])
```

Comment: It might be misleading -  dosth is not a function, but code executed in module 2. It uses either list 1 or the newly created list2. I will edit my post, to make this clear.

Comment: It's a long-winded prime factor analysis, the code wouldn't contribute to this question. The idea is that some modules might have already a pre-computated prime number list `list1`, while `module 2` should also work ad hoc for a single very large number.